# Is there a youtube for desktop that uses very less resources? Or how can I reduce the amount of resources used by youtube?

Tags: ubuntu, youtube

I was using windows, now I'm on ubuntu because although all tests were fine, I suspect something has failed. Whenever I play youtube video, even ubuntu randomly crashes. It's unpredictable. But the chance to crash increases as the number of tabs increases. The catch is I need to use many tabs and I watch them one by one to filter which one is good.

So, is there a way to reduce resources? I am opening 5 tabs at once to reduce resources, but it's still getting freezed.

Comment: Have you tried using adblocking plugins to reduce the Javascript being loaded?  Also, have you tried an alternative browser and flushing your browser cache?  What you are advising does not seem typical behaviour.

Comment: Relatedly, have you looked at your memory usage?   Also, if you are using Firefox, the url "about:performance"  can show you which tabs are consuming memory and CPU - it might give you some clues.

Comment: Do you have swap enabled?